# How to create SharePoint 2013 User Group using LDAP Java API

Tags: java, sharepoint, ldap

How do I create a user group in SharePoint 2013 using the LDAP Java API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this code i craete the group in AD using JAVA LDAP

```
String entryDNGroup = "CN=" + groupName +","+aDauthSettings.getDomainCreateUserPath();
            try{
                Attributes attrsGroup = new BasicAttributes(true);
                // Create the objectclass to add
                Attribute objClassesGroup = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");
                objClassesGroup.add("group");
                attrsGroup.put(objClassesGroup);                
                attrsGroup.put("samAccountName", groupName);
                attrsGroup.put("cn", groupName);

                ldapContext.createSubcontext(entryDNGroup, attrsGroup);
                return true;
            } catch (NameAlreadyBoundException e) {
                return false;
            } catch (OperationNotSupportedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure can we add a user group to SharePoint site via LDAP java API.

But we can add user group via SharePoint `UserGroup` SOAP web service. In this web service we can use `AddGroup` method to create a user group.

**Reference :**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms774470%28v=office.12%29.aspx

Comment: thanks for your time.i take reference of this code and wirte simmlar code in java  but this one is not work in java LDAP